# LWC Feature erring with `Received exception event aura:systemError from server`

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, promises

I randomly began having a strange error appear that I'm having trouble debugging, all it tells me is: `Received exception event aura:systemError from server`

What I have is a "Reports" LWC that shows reports (graphs and tables) of different aggregated data points that are unattainable through the Reports tab. The part receiving the error is a table where each row is a `Course` and it's rows are `Number of Enrollments`, `Number of Completions`, and `Average Competency Level Change`. For the last column, a user self-rates their competency level (1-5) at the beginning and end of a course, the last column represents the average competency level increase among all students who have taken that course.

To achieve this I have 3 APEX functions: `getCourseEnrollments`, `getCourseCompletions`, and `getCourseAssessmentScores`, where the first two get the total count of enrollments/completions for every course using 1 query, and the last retrieving all assessment scores for a course and calculating the average competency level increase.

I call these functions using promises from the JS end like so:

```
promiseArray = [
  getCourseEnrollments({courses: courses}), 
  getCourseCompletions({courses: courses})
];

// The courseAssessmentScores function
courses.forEach(id => {
  promiseArray.push(
    getCourseAssessmentScores({...}) 
  )
})


return Promise.all(promiseArray).then(promiseArray => {
  // All data received, now put together table
}).catch(error => {
  // handle error
});
```

This chunk of code gets called in two ways:

1. When updating the table that shows 5 courses at a time (thus the promise array is a max of 7 method calls)
2. When downloading the table that will download all courses at a time (we currently have 23 courses, so there will be 25 method calls in the promise array

Keep in mind, our `User` is a custom object and with these reports, you are able to filter the results based on certain User criteria.

- When I am paging through the table, I receive no errors and everything loads fine.
- When I download the table with no User filter, it works fine.
- If I toggle on the `role` filter and filter for only `standard` users, and page through the table, I revive no errors and everything loads fine.
- However, if the `role` filter is on `standard` and I attempt to download the table, that is when I receive the error in my console `Received exception event aura:systemError from server`.

When I look in the Salesforce Logs, there are no errors, all the APEX methods succeeded (although there are only about 9 of the 25 that were called in the Promise array, so I'm thinking this isn't an APEX limit error or else the error would appear there.

Because it works when I don't have a filter on (causing even more data to be handled), I don't think it could be an issue with the number of calls in the Promise array because they are the same for each (25)...

Any ideas on what else could be causing this issue?

Comment: I don't think we have enough code to help you. What's the relevant part of the apex? What's the download method?

Comment: I don't believe it's APEX because I'm not seeing any errors in the APEX logs. All the APEX methods do is make an SOQL query and then return. The download method is the user clicks a button and the on-click event triggers off the code I've provided.

Comment: I guess check the parameters to see if something's off? The bits you're omitting might be related. FYI, there's a much easier way to write your code in LWC: `promiseArray = [getCourseEnrollments({ courses }), getCourseCompletions({ courses }), ...courses.map(id => getCourseAssessmentScores({ ... }))];`

Comment: Okay, I'll work on adding that code... I double checked the parameters and they are all fine. Remember how I was able to page through all the table pages (displays 5 at a time) successfully, but downloading all at the same time didn't work. So when the promise array contains a subset of function calls (getCourseAssessmentScores for 5 different courses) it works fine for every subset. But when the whole set (getCourseAssessmentScores for all different courses) that's when the error occurs. Is it possible that the LWC has a promise limitation of some sort?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It might need some deeper digging to get to the core of this. There's no reason I know of that this should happen aside from possibly bad parameters or something.